# Drawing a Linked List using GridView at run time - How to perform Data Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I'm building a C# WPF app (for learning purposes) that draws a linked list based on the data input by the user.  I've created AddItem/DeleteItem buttons and corresponding text boxes.  Wen user enters an item and Presses Add Item button, the corresponding element is to be drawn, with red line separaters between two elements.

I'm using GridView to display the linked list elements.
Corresponding XAML code is below :

```
<Grid x:Name="ListDrawGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
```

I'm currently using C# code to populate data into these elements like below.  The below function is called whenever "Add" Button is pressed and new data is inserted into the linked list (ILinkedList is the interface to my custom LinkedList class which maintains the actual list).

```
public void DrawList(ILinkedList list)
        {
            int col_index = 0;
            int row_index = 1;
            GridDrawArea.Children.Clear();

            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                if (col_index >= MaxCols-1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                TextBlock t = new TextBlock()
                {
                    Text = i,
                    FontSize = 15,
                    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                    //Width = 15,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    //VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
                };


                Grid.SetRow(t,row_index);
                Grid.SetColumn(t, col_index);
                col_index++;
                GridDrawArea.Children.Add(t);

                Path line = new Path
                {
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    // VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
                    StrokeThickness = 4,
                    Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                    Stretch = Stretch.Fill,

                };
                LineGeometry lg = new LineGeometry();
                lg.StartPoint = new Point(0,col_index);
                lg.EndPoint = new Point (0,col_index + 1);
                line.Data = lg;

                Grid.SetRow(line, row_index);
                Grid.SetColumn(line, col_index);
                col_index++;

                GridDrawArea.Children.Add(line);

            }
            TextBlock tnull = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = "NULL",
                FontSize = 15,
                //FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                //Width = 15,
            };
            Grid.SetRow(tnull, row_index);
            Grid.SetColumn(tnull, col_index);
            GridDrawArea.Children.Add(tnull);
        }
```

But I feel this is not the correct way of doing things. I'm looking for a way to bind the Grid to the linked list backend code such that, the data is updated whenever a new element is added. If I've to do the same using Data Binding, how should I go about it ?  If you need any other information from my end , please let me know.

NOTE: ListDrawGrid and GridDrawArea are the same.  I've two different vars as they are in different classes.  ListDrawGrid is in the main....xaml.cs and GridDrawArea is in another class and it's initialized with ListDrawGrid at init time.

Comment: What is `GridDrawArea` ? You dont reference it on the Xaml.. In XAML you have `ListDrawGrid`

Comment: GridDrawArea is same as ListDrawGrid.  GridDrawArea is in a different class and it's initialized with ListDrawGrid.

Comment: I'm not really following your reasoning. You have one grid in the Xaml. In the code behind you receive a `LinkedList` and then you just have to set the `ListViewGrid.ItemsSource = list`. Why the `GridViewArea`

Comment: My reasoning might be flawed since I'm still new to this.  I'm having a different class called GraphicsEngine to draw list in the main window.  The GraphicsEngine window has this var - GridViewArea.  I create an instance of this GraphicsEngine class and populate the GridViewArea with the ListViewGrid during initialization in Main....Xaml.cs

Comment: Then post the other class, or ditch the `GridViewArea` cause I don't see why should you even have her.

Comment: It should be the other way around when you say this - "and populate the GridViewArea with the ListViewGrid during initialization"